# RegionPlot of the Maximum of a function

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

For the function `fun[a_, b_, x_, y_] = Sin[a x] Cos[b y] (a x + b y);`corresponding to $x$ and $y$, I need a RegionPlot showing the maximum of function $fun[a, b, x, y]>0.5$ such that the maximization is carried over $a,b\in [0,1000]$.

A failed attempt: `RegionPlot[{NMaximize[ fun[a, b, x, y] > 0.5, {a, 0, 1000}, {b, 0, 1000}]}, {x, 0,  2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`

Comment: Is this really that difficult?

Comment: it looks like the region will be the whole x-y region (`Rectangle[{0,0},{2Pi, 2Pi}]`)  if threshold is less than  `MaxValue[{fun[a,b,x,y], 0<=a<=1000,0<=b<=1000,0<=x<=2Pi,0<=y<=2Pi}, {a,b,x,y}]` and empty region otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Inequalities are boolean expressions; they do not have maximums and minimums.

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

fun[a_, b_, x_, y_] = Sin[a x] Cos[b y] (a x + b y);

NMaximize[{fun[a, b, x, y], 0 <= a <= 1000, 0 <= b <= 1000, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi, 
   0 <= y <= 2 Pi}, {a, b, x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // N

(* {2797.59, {a -> 404.339, b -> 595.551, x -> 3.68672, y -> 2.19444}} *)
```

For nonlinear expressions, [`NMaximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html) generally only finds a local maximum.

Using a non-default [`Method`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method.html) provides a better result:

```
(sol = {#, NMaximize[{
          fun[a, b, x, y], 0 <= a <= 1000, 0 <= b <= 1000, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi, 
          0 <= y <= 2 Pi},
         {a, b, x, y},
         WorkingPrecision -> 20,
         Method -> #]} & /@
      {Automatic, "NelderMead", 
       "DifferentialEvolution", "SimulatedAnnealing"} //
     SortBy[#, #[[2, 1]] &] &) // N //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

```
(param = sol[[4, 2, 2, 1 ;; 2]]) // N

(* {a -> 973.25, b -> 1000.} *)
```

Due to the complicated nature of the region's structure, this is quite slow.

```
RegionPlot[(fun[x, y, a, b] /. param) > 1/2,
 {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

Using a much higher threshold.

```
RegionPlot[(fun[x, y, a, b] /. param) > 2500,
 {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: Write fun= `(ax + by) Cos[by] Sin[ax] ` with ax==a*x, bx==b*x, regard the two terms separated, with the help of `Maximize[{Sin[ax] Cos[by], 2 Pi 998 < ax < 2 Pi 1000, 
  2 Pi 998 < by < 2 Pi 1000}, {ax, by}, Reals] `  to get the two equal maxima `NMaximize[{(ax + by) Cos[by] Sin[ax], 2 Pi 999 < ax < 2 Pi 1000, 
  2 Pi 999 < by < 2 Pi 1000}, {ax, by}] `  `{12561.7, {ax -> 6281.61, by -> 6280.04}} ` and `NMaximize[{(ax + by) Cos[by] Sin[ax], 2 Pi 999 < ax < 2 Pi 1000, 
  2 Pi 999 < by < 2 Pi 1000}, {ax, by}, 
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"] ` `{12561.7, {ax -> 6278.47, by -> 6283.19}} `

Comment: max is `(7997 \[Pi])/2 `